# No selecciona los datos de las td marcados checkbox

Tags: javascript, html5, checkbox, jtable

¿Por qué la siguiente expresión, que aparece en el código, no selecciona la información seleccionada por mí?.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este código que fue una Grand ayuda de un colaborador de la comunidad, parte  de ello dinámicamente ya mi funciona bien, pero mi falta organizar la tabla.
La idea es que, en cada CHECKBOX marcado, seleccione la categoría correspondiente y luego la cantidad / producto / precio unitario. Y así puedes enviar por whatsapp.
Adjunto imagen de la tabla que me gustaría generar para enviar por whatsapp.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```js
let tabela,
    linhas,
    checks,
    otros,
    tot,
    cant,
    totalParts;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    tabela = document.querySelector('#minhaTabela1','#minhaTabela2');
    linhas = tabela.querySelectorAll('tr');
    checks = document.querySelectorAll('.mis-checkboxes');
    otros = document.querySelectorAll('.mis-adicionales');
    cants = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    tot = document.querySelector('#total');
    let btnVisualizar = document.getElementById("enviar");
    
     var dados = "";
     
 checks.forEach(check => {
    
        if(check.checked) {
        for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
    var selecionado = linhas[i];
     selecionado = selecionado.getElementsByTagName("td");
     dados += " / " + selecionado[0].innerHTML + " - " +  selecionado[2].innerHTML + " - " + "Precio unitario:  " + selecionado[1].innerText + "\n"; 
        }    
       }
    });  

    checks.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', comprobar));

    otros.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', comprobar));

    cants.forEach(item => {
     
        item.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.select());

        item.addEventListener('change', calcular);
    });

    btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function(){
        
        btnVisualizar = window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=520000000&text='Solicito:   " + dados + ',' +  "\n" + '- TOTAL: MX$'   +  totalParts);
    });
});

function comprobar(e) {
 
    let textInput = document.querySelector(`#TEXT-${e.target.id}`);
    if (e.target.checked) {
        textInput.value = 1;
    } else {
        textInput.value = '';
    }
    calcular();
}

function calcular() {

    let calc = 0;
 
    checks.forEach(check => {
    
        if(check.checked) {
    
            let cantidad = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#TEXT-${check.id}`).value) || 0;
     
            calc += parseFloat(check.getAttribute('tu-attr-precio')) * cantidad;
            
        }
    });

    otros.forEach(item => {
        calc += parseFloat(item.value);
    });

    totalParts = parseFloat(calc).toFixed(2).split('.');
    tot.value = totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' +  (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : '00');
}
```

```html
<div class="inner4">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3 >tabla 1(categoria)</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="inner3">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                                
                                <div class="table-wrapper">
                                    <table class="alt1" id="minhaTabela">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 1</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE1" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="22" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE1">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 2</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE2" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="12" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE2">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php } } ?>
                                        
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner4">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3 >tabla 2(categoria)</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="inner3">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                                
                                <div class="table-wrapper">
                                    <table class="alt1" id="minhaTabela">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 1</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE3" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="22" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE1">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 2</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE4" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="12" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE2">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php } } ?>
                                        
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                
                                   <div class="table-wrapper">
                                    <table class="alt1">
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr  style="font-size: 23px">
                                        <td class="wabi">TOTAL A PAGAR</td>
                                        <td class="cheq"></td>
                                        <td style="aling-text: center" class="cheq" ><output type="text" readonly id="total" placeholder="0.00" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv7QK.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv7QK.png)

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Gracias Bicho, lo encontré y ya estás ok. El desafío ahora es montar el envio. como en la imagen. Con nombre de las categorías e sus productos relacionados

Comment: Alguien que pueda ayudarme??

Comment: @Bicho, conoces esas expresiones?

Comment: Los datos son dinámicos?

Comment: sí, hizo esta simulación, pero los tengo dinámicamente generados por PHP.

Comment: Cuántas cantidades y precios unitarios debe haber por cada categoría? Según la imagen 2?

Comment: Bueno, eso cambia, pero ahora tengo en cada tabla algo como 8 a 10. Pero a la medida que llene el banco puede ser más. Él Grand reto es que no logró seleccionar correctamente y hacer salir solamente los que los checkbox están on.

Comment: Es complicado dar una solución óptima por la complejidad de tu propuesta. Los `id` de los checkbox y de los `textbox` igual deben ser dinámicos, en Jquery es fácil conocer cuál checkbox está activo, entonces dentro de cada uno deberías tener un `for` para crear los textbox con el `id` del nodo master Ej: `id="1_1"` `id="1_2"`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque es posible hacerlo con varias tablas, te recomiendo usar solo una, principalmente para que todo tenga la misma medida. Tampoco es recomendable crear la salida con cada modificación, solo se necesita cuando se hace clic en el botón Enviar.

Al enviar, recorres todos los *checkboxes* y agregas a la salida solo los que están marcados, usando [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para dar formato a la salida, sin tener que concatenar y dejando el código más legible:

```js
let tabela,
    linhas,
    checks,
    otros,
    tot,
    cant,
    totalParts;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Estas dos variables no son necesarias:
        // tabela = document.querySelector('#minhaTabela');
        // linhas = tabela.querySelectorAll('tr');
    checks = document.querySelectorAll('.mis-checkboxes');
    otros = document.querySelectorAll('.mis-adicionales');
    cants = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    tot = document.querySelector('#total');
    let btnVisualizar = document.getElementById("enviar");
     
    checks.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', comprobar));
    otros.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', comprobar));
    cants.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.select());
        item.addEventListener('change', calcular);
    });
    
    // Asignar evento al botón enviar
    btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Crear la variable de salida y total
        let dados = '';
        let total = 0;
        // Recorrer checkboxes
        checks.forEach(check => {
            // Solo si está marcado
            if(check.checked) {
                // Variables para producto, cantidad y precio
                // El producto está en la primera celda de la fila
                let prod = check.closest('tr').querySelector('td').innerText;
                let cant = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#TEXT-${check.id}`).value) || 0;
                let precio = parseFloat(check.getAttribute('tu-attr-precio'));
                if(cant > 0) {
                    // Solo si cantidad es mayor que cero
                    // Realizar cálculos
                    let subt = cant * precio;
                    total += subt;
                    // Agregar producto a salida
                    dados += `${cant} ${prod} (${precio}) ${subt}\n`;
                }
            }
        });
        if(total == 0) {
            alert('Selecciona al menos un producto.');
        } else {
            dados += `Total a pagar: ${total}`;
            console.log(dados);
            // window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=520000000&text='Solicito:   " + dados);
        }
    });  
});

function comprobar(e) {
    let textInput = document.querySelector(`#TEXT-${e.target.id}`);
    if (e.target.checked) {
        textInput.value = 1;
    } else {
        textInput.value = '';
    }
    calcular();
}

function calcular() {
    let calc = 0;
    checks.forEach(check => {
        if(check.checked) {
            let cantidad = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#TEXT-${check.id}`).value) || 0;
            calc += parseFloat(check.getAttribute('tu-attr-precio')) * cantidad;
        }
    });

    otros.forEach(item => {
        calc += parseFloat(item.value);
    });
    totalParts = parseFloat(calc).toFixed(2).split('.');
    tot.value = totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' +  (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : '00');
}
```

```html
<div class="inner4">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3 >tabla 1(categoria)</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="inner3">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                                
                                <div class="table-wrapper">
                                    <table class="alt1" id="minhaTabela">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 1</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE1" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="22" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE1">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 2</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE2" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="12" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE1"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE2">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php } } ?>
                                        
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner4">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3 >tabla 2(categoria)</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="inner3">
                    <div class="wrapper style1">
                        <div class="content">
                                
                                <div class="table-wrapper">
                                    <table class="alt1" id="minhaTabela">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 3</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE3" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="22" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE3"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE3">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class="nome" >produto 4</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="checkbox" id="CLASE4" name="CLASE1" tu-attr-precio="12" class="mis-checkboxes" />
                                                    <label for="CLASE4"></label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" id="TEXT-CLASE4">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                
                                   <div class="table-wrapper">
                                    <table class="alt1">
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr  style="font-size: 23px">
                                        <td class="wabi">TOTAL A PAGAR</td>
                                        <td class="cheq"></td>
                                        <td style="aling-text: center" class="cheq" ><output type="text" readonly id="total" placeholder="0.00" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Hola nuevamente @Triby, muchas gracias por su ayuda. El gran problema es que las dos tablas tienen diseños diferentes entre sí y como se generan dinámicamente, lo que estaba haciendo era generar una tabla limitada a dos categorías y luego generar otra a partir de la tercera, para poder tener dos tablas gráficamente diferentes .

Comment: Creo que me abre un nuevo desafío, que sería tener una sola tabla y poder hacer que el CSS para las dos primeras categorías sea una y luego elegir un CSS diferente para la tercera.  No sé si puedo expresar mi idea con claridad.

Comment: Ahí está con dos tablas y sigue funcionando. Puedes tener tantas tablas como quieras, solo asegúrate de tener correctamente IDs y clases.

Comment: Cada vez descubro que sé menos y necesito estudiar mucho más. Muchas bendiciones para ti @Triby y gracias por la ayuda. Continuaré el viaje, ahora intentaré entender para que cada categoría aparezca antes que los productos a los que pertenece. Vlw